# How to install widgetset on Intellij gradle project

Tags: gradle, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Gradle Intelij (community edition) project.

I want to use Vaadin plugin (CSValidationWidgetset), but I am lost how I can install this.

As I am using Spring Boot I am managed to set up this plugin in widget list. I've  added following line to app.prop:

```
server.context_parameters.widgetset=com.vaadin.csvalidation.widgetset.CSValidationWidgetset
```

But now I can see that during server startup it is trying to get some resources related to this plugin. What files exactly should I provide? Is there any gradle task to do such kind of activity?

Thanks
Pawel

Comment: are you using the vaadin gradle plugin? have you compiled the widgetset by any means?

Comment: I do not use vaading gradle plugin so far. With this plugin, which task I need to run? Would it be compatible with Spring project? Is there any way to do this same w/o this plugin?

Comment: yes it works.  if you dont want to use it, you can write all on your own (but why).  see an example here: https://github.com/christoph-frick/springboot-groovy-vaadin-starter